# Windows 8 behaviors library?

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

We need library for Windows 8 Metro Style app which provides the same functionality as **System.Windows.Interactivity** and **Microsoft.Expression.Interactions** libs do for Silverlight / Windows Phone apps.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Systm.Windows.Interactivity don't exist for Metro style apps.

You'll need to use the following: [Winrt Behaviours](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) and [Winrt Triggers](http://winrttriggers.codeplex.com/).  You'll need to code the behaviors you get in Blend yourself.